# JavaFX - Get Actual Computed-Size of HBOX

Tags: javafx

I have a simple `HBOX` control which uses `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` in `Pref-Height`, hence the size is all calculated and adjusted by the controls inside, which are a couple `VBOX`.

The issue comes when I try to add a new `Pane` as a children to the `HBOX` and draw a vertical line from top to bottom of the `HBOX`, so I write my line:

```
int startX = 5;
int startY = 0;
int endX = 5;
Line line = new Line(startX,startY,endX,hbox.getHeight());
```

Here, I need the `hbox.getHeight()`, but surprise: it is `=-1`, because it is using `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`. So, how can I get the real (computed) value of `hbox.getHeight()`?

Comment: This sounds a bit like an x-y problem. If the real requirement is just to have a vertical line running the length of the hbox, 5 pixels from the left edge, that can be achieved with CSS. (At the very most, you could wrap the hbox in a custom pane in which you override `layoutChildren()`.)

Comment: @James_D Certainly, I could use `CSS`, but the line is not ornamental, it is more like a dynamic line which needs some programming and periodic adjustments depending on the values of other controls.

Comment: _hbox.getHeight(), but surprise: it is =-1, because it is using USE_COMPUTED_SIZE_ no - height is only negative if it's not yet layouted .. so time for a [mcve]

Comment: @kleopatra why the down-vote? isn't this a legitimate question?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I think you can do something like:

```
public class HBoxWithLine extends HBox {

    // Example of configurable property:
    private final DoubleProperty lineOffset = new SimpleDoubleProperty(5);

    public DoubleProperty lineOffsetProperty() {
        return lineOffset ;
    }

    public final double getLineOffset() {
        return lineOffsetProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setLineOffset(double lineOffset) {
        lineOffsetProperty().set(lineOffset);
    }

    private final Line line = new Line();

    public HBoxWithLine() {
        getChildren().add(line);
        // request layout when offset is invalidated:
        lineOffset.addListener(obs -> requestLayout());
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        line.setStartX(getLineOffset());
        line.setEndX(getLineOffset());
        line.setStartY(0);
        line.setEndY(getHeight());
        super.layoutChildren();
    }
}
```

Now you can just create a `HBoxWithLine` and add (additional) child nodes to it, set it's pref width and height to either fixed values, or `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`, etc., and it should just work.

Comment: answering x-y-problems is a lottery- might hit the nail in its head .. or not :))